# In Titanium how do I get video to play in Android?

Tags: android, titanium

In Titanium 1.6.1 I can get Android 2.2 to play video on Kitchen Sink, but have been unable to get video to play outside of Kitchen Sink on Android.  I'd like the smallest code snippet possible to play a video in Android.

In my current attempt I tried using the movie_embed.js from Kitchen Sink in a new project's app.js file like this:

```
var btnPlayMovie = Titanium.UI.createButton({
    text: 'Click me',
    left: 10,
    height: 30,
    top: 100
});

btnPlayMovie.addEventListener('click', function(){

    var win = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
        url:'./movie_embed.js',
        title:'Test movie'
    });
    //various methods of opening the window win.open(), Ti.UI.currentTab.open(win, {animated:true}), etc
    //none have worked either erroring or showing a black screen.
});
```

it works in iPhone, but not in Android 2.2

Comment: Which Android device are you testing on?

Comment: can you post the code in movie_embed.js ?

Comment: @Brian I'm using the movie_embed.js from Kitchen Sink since that works in Kitchen Sink on my test machine: https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/blob/master/demos/KitchenSink/Resources/examples/movie_embed.js

Comment: @David - Sorry should have asked what hardware device or are you running on the emulator?

Comment: @Morrison, no worries. We tested it on Huawei IDEOS S7 running Android 2.1 and got the same black screen we get in the emulator running 2.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend not trying to do video in Titanium.

We have video working in 1.6.2. Right now we only have 2 videos playing in it.  What will play is very limited. I'm guessing it is encoding issues. Also the video opens in a new Window, we can't change the url of an existing video, and have other issues.